# Tangent as limit of secants

Tags: calculus

Why is the tangent line to a curve is defined as the limiting position of the secant lines and not the final,actual position of the secant lines when the two points actually coincide?

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: That would be because the final position is *not* a secant, having only *one* intersection point with the curve, generally.

Comment: Yves Daoust I saw people posting that it is the limiting position,but I dont know why

Comment: As a general practice, if you are asking about something someone posted, edit the question so it includes a link to the post. You can include multiple links if you have seen this in multiple places. Then someone may be able to explain what those other people said.

Comment: One reason people like to talk about the limiting position is because it lets us answer questions like [Problem with basic definition of a tangent line.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1748162/139123)

Comment: David in your link,i went through the answers and people have mentioned that it is the limiting position when a point approaches the other?But why limit?Why not the scenario where two points actually co incide?